# Object not found for lapply data.table within function

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have the following R code:

```
library(data.table)
L <- list(a=data.table(x=c(1,2,3),y=c(10,20,30)),
          b=data.table(x=c(4,5,6),y=c(40,50,60)),
          c=data.table(x=c(7,8,9),y=c(70,80,90)))


columnName <- "x"         
r <- lapply(L,"[",i=get(columnName) %in% c(1,4))

f <- function(L1) {
     columnName1 <- "x"
     r1 <- lapply(L1,"[",i=get(columnName1) %in% c(1,4))
     return(r1)
}

r1 <- f(L)
```

My question is: Why does the assignment to r1 at the bottom fail inside the function with

> Error in get(columnName1) : object 'columnName1' not found

The assigment to r further up works fine. Likewise, if, inside the function I change it to a global assignment for columnName1 via <<-, but then I have created a global variable which I don't really want.... How can I cleanly rewrite this such that data.table finds columnName1 within its scope? And what am I missing about scoping? I would have thought that if it can't find columnName1 within the "[" function it will look one environment "up" and find it there? It must look in the global environment though, but not in the parent?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing slight what you're looking to return from the `data.table`.  If you're looking to return rows where column `x` equals 1 and 4 it's usually easier to get it to work with a single value from the list and then get it to work with `lapply`

```
library(data.table)
columnName1 <- "x"
L$a[get(columnName1) %in% c(1,4)]
```

to iterate through the list

```
lapply(L, function(x) x[get(columnName1) %in% c(1,4)])
```

if you want a function that can specify the column name and row numbers

```
f <- function(list, col, row) {lapply(list, function(x, lcol, lrow) x[get(lcol) %in% lrow], lcol=col, lrow=row)}
f(L, "x", c(1,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `lapply` sugar syntax probably complicates things here, in which case the expression will be treated as arguments, which makes it harder to know which environment the expression is evaluated. Also the `get()` function has been probably modified when used with `data.table()` since the signature is different than normal use case. One work around here is to create your own anonymous function which guarantees that the `get` will be evaluated within `[.data.table` call.

```
f <- function(L1) {
     columnName1 <- "x"
     r1 <- lapply(L1, function(x) x[i=get(columnName1) %in% c(1,4)])
     r1
}

r1 <- f(L)

r1
#$a
#   x  y
#1: 1 10

#$b
#   x  y
#1: 4 40

#$c
#Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: x,y
```

Still not sure what causes the failure, probably some `data.table` experts can clarify here.

Comment: Using an anonymous function worked. I guess I was pushing it with "[" combined with lapply and data.table.

Comment: @user5577796 it might have to do with the environment for `lapply` when using optional arguments.  It works if you have your original function `f` use `columnName` which resides in the global environment instead of `columnName1`